# tikz callout shape not working with alltt environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, verbatim

I want to use the `callout` shape from `tikz` in order to explain some elements of a program listed in an `alltt` environment. But the `callout` shape is not pointing correctly to the desired element in the listing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={7cm,2cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.callouts}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}%workaround for undefined \pgf@test

\newcommand{\refnode}[2]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=-.5ex]{\node[draw](#1){#2};}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alltt}
let \refnode{r}{greatest} a b =
  if a > b then a else b
\end{alltt}

\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{%
  \node[rectangle callout,fill=green!30,callout absolute pointer={(r)}]
     at (4,0) {function name};}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Any clues on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be missing an `overlay` parameter at the `\node` defining the callout.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={7cm,2cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}%workaround for undefined \pgf@test

\newcommand{\refnode}[2]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=-.5ex]{%
    \node[draw](#1){#2};
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{alltt}
let \refnode{r}{greatest} a b =
  if a > b then a else b
\end{alltt}

\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{%
  \node[rectangle callout,fill=green!30,overlay,%
    callout absolute pointer={(r.east)}] at (4,0) {function name};
}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]